# Reasonable payment providers to allow African countries to pay a UK Business

Tags: payments, monetize

One of my sites has a fairly large following in Uganda and Mauritius (although in actual percentage terms African nations would rank quite low).

We currently do most of our processing through Paypal for memberships and donations but they do not allow people from these counties to sign up, nor do the handful of other payment providers we have used in the past.

Has anyone had any experience accepting money from Africa?

Ideally the customer would pay no extra charges bar what they are sending us.

Comment: Accepting payments from Africa is very high risk due to the amount of fraud originating from there. I'd be surprised if you found a provider that allowed you to accept payments from there and had fees anywhere near what Paypal offers.

Comment: @John - yeah, I knew it was going to be a tough one.  I was hoping maybe some provider based in some country that is more relaxed about African payments would exist - seems not to be the case.  Unless anyone else comes forward do you want to put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: done. Hopefully we're both wrong and there is a viable solution posted here.

Comment: No answer appearing at the moment, presumably a caching issue.

Comment: Weird. It's gone for me, too. Maybe I'm going crazy. repost it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accepting payments from Africa is very high risk due to the amount of fraud originating from there. I'd be surprised if you found a provider that allowed you to accept payments from there and had fees anywhere near what Paypal offers.